# vuex + typescript + namespace modules: accessing other module state

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using vuex with typescript and namespaces module.
I have 2 module: "UserProfile" and "Trips".
Everything works inside a single module.

I need to access the current user, stored inside "UserProfile" module state, from inside an action of "Trip" module.

As far as I understand, I could use rootState["profile/user"] if I use no typescirpt.

But with typescript, compiler gives me an error like this:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'RootState' has no index signature.
```

This is my action from "Trip" module:

```
async createTrip({ commit, state, rootState, rootGetters}) {
    const user = rootState["profile/user"];
}
```

Anyone knows the right way to access a state owned by another namespaced modules when using vuex + typescript?

Thanks.

===== UPDATE =====

At the moment, the only working solution I found is this:

1] For each module creating a getter returning its entire state (i.e. "Profile" module adds a getter returning ProfileState type)

2] Using that getter through rootGetters from another module like this:

```
 async createTrip({ commit, state, rootState, rootGetters}) {
    const profileState: ProfileState= rootGetters["profile/getState"];
    if(profileState.user === undefined ) return;
    console.log("CurrentUser: " + profileState.user.uid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But with typescript, compiler gives me an error like this:
>
> `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'RootState' has no index signature.`

This error States that in your type declaration you missed to add the definition:

e.g:

```
export type RootState = {
  //...
  profile?: ProfileState
}
```

or

```
export type RootState = {
  //...
  [k in keyof ModuleStateTypes]?: ModuleStateTypes[k] 
}
```

[Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, cant one simply add those modules in the rootState typedef?
like so:

```
{ ...; moduleName?: moduleState;}
```

or even:

```
{ ...; [key: string | number]: any;}
```

Comment: This could not be providing an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).